# What is the color code for iOS system labels in both light and dark mode?

Tags: ios

Human Interface Guidelines, "Color" section talks about the using system color is preferred. There are color codes for all system colors however for the foreground content text color there only APIs provided.

So what exactly is the color code for labels in both light and dark mode? Our designers need these colors for their mockup.

https://developer.apple.com/design/human-interface-guidelines/ios/visual-design/color/

The color code fetched from the Playground does not seem right. The hex codes are all the same.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Food for thought: "Instead of trying to create custom colors that match the system colors, use the dynamic system colors." I read this in the link you shared. Not sure if this answers your question, just thought it may prove itself useful.

Comment: Yes, we are going to use the system color in code but we want these color code for our designer so they can use in their mockup.

Comment: Ah, okay. That makes sense. Best of luck.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The RGB values of secondary, tertiary, and quaternary label colour are *in fact* the same. They only differ in the *alpha* value, which you might have forgotten about :)

From what I observed:

- Label colour has 100% alpha
- Secondary label colour has 60% alpha
- Tertiary label colour has 30% alpha
- Quaternary label colour has 18% alpha

Here's another way to find the hex value of a system colour. Go to the asset catalog of an Xcode project. Add a colour set:

[image]

Then, select "Any Appearance" or "Dark Appearance" depending on which one you want ("Any Apperance" means "not dark"). You can even check the "High Contrast" box to have more options for how your dynamic colour will look depending on the situation.

Then select your desired colour from the "Content" dropdown (see freehand circle).

[image]

Finally, you can click on "Show Color Panel" to see the hex:

[image]